# Check String with only Numbers in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I have string which has numbers and text. (Numbers have decimal values too.) I would like to check the strings contains **only** numbers with decimal values.

Here is the string:

```
String testValue = "One Time Password(OTP) for Debit Card ending 1234 is 359573. Pls use this OTP at HDFC Bank ATM(Language selection screen) to create your ATM PIN before 27Jan15"
```

I am extracting the value to get only number in another piece of code. which I am storing in testValue. Sometime I get the full message like above and for which I am trying to find if the testValue has only numbers...So 
I tried the following:

```
if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", testValue ) == false && testValue.length() > 2) 
{
  Log.e("True","Only numbers);                  
}
```

This is printing True.

```
if (testValue.contains("[0-9]+"))
{
    Log.e("True","Only numbers);
}
```

This is printing True too.

```
if (testValue.matches(".*\\d+.*")
{
        Log.e("True","Only numbers);
    }
```

This is printing True too.

All the above conditions are printing true I am not sure why as it contains numbers and alphabets?

How do I get check if testValue has only numbers (decimals too)

Thanks!

Comment: use TextUtil.isDigit()

Comment: Tried TextUtil. This is doesn't work

Comment: use TextUtils.isDigitsOnly();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", testValue ) == false` will be true if `testValue` is not all letters.

`testValue.contains("[0-9]+")` returns true if there is at least one digit in `testValue`.

`testValue.matches(".*\\d+.*")` also returns true if there is at least one digit in `testValue`.

To test for only digits, use the middle one, but with `matches()`:

`testValue.matches("[0-9]+")`

If you also want to allow an optional `.` with one or more digits after, you can use:

`testValue.matches("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?")`

Comment: Faster than me. +1 for the explanation of each error and the correct answer to the question :)

Comment: Now nothing is getting printed. Even the string that has numbers. For eg: 1419496.58

Comment: Perfect. I was near but couldn't get it working. Thanks anyways! @Keppil

Answer (score 0):

```html
String testValue = "One Time Password(OTP) for Debit Card ending 1234 is 359573. Pls use this OTP at HDFC Bank ATM(Language selection screen) to create your ATM PIN before 27Jan15";
 if (testValue.contains("[a-zA-Z]+")&&(testValue.contains("."))) 
 {
   System.out.println("True Only numbers");                  
 }
 else 
  System.out.println("false");

}
```

Comment: I don't require text. I require check if string has only numbers with decimal too.